# Number of vehicles and messages received

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using a custom code configuration of veins, namely [this branch](https://github.com/VeReMi-dataset/veins/tree/securecomm2018). However, I have not been able to locate where I can specify the number of vehicles in a simulation, as well as the number of messages a vehicle can receive. The reason I ask this is because I am hoping for a small (~20) number of vehicles in the simulation, and some to receive upwards of 10,000+ messages over the course of the simulation from each other.

Can anyone guide me as to what I need to do to configure this specific for this custom code configuration? Is it just a matter of running the simulation for an extended period of time? Is there any way to specify the number of vehicles in the simulation, however? I can't find it in the current `omnetpp.ini` file in `simulations/lust/` (it uses the LUST scenario).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that specific simulation, but from my experience so far the number of vehicles is controlled by SUMO and not by OMNeT++. I'd probably check the route files that are used in the launchd.xml.

Answer (score 0):

In the `simulations/lust` folder you find the `.sumocfg` files which in turn tell you which route files sumo loads. There are several which all together define your vehicles. I don't know which of these vehicles actually send messages but if you want to adapt the number of vehicles, change these files. If you just want to scale the overall demand you can als o add something like `<scale value="0.5"/>` to the sumocfg. But then you don't have control which vehicles are removed.